# Swift: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT after storyBoard.instantiateViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I want switch user to another page

I use this code :

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vcAboutUs = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIndex") 
self.present(vcAboutUs, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But after run project i am getting `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error and simulator crashed

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1uIT.jpg

Full code :

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  let getJsonLogin = GetData()
  let result = getJsonLogin.getJson(urlGet: AppDelegate.ADDRESS+"/index.php", urlData: "mobile="+mobile+"&code="+getCode+"") { result in
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if(result == nil){
      self.progressText.text = "Error";
    } else {
      if((result!["error"]!) == "true"){
        self.progressTextCode.text = result!["message"]!;
      } else {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vcAboutUs = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIndex") 
        self.present(vcAboutUs, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: most probably `vcAboutUs` is nil, are you sure there is a viewController in Main storyboard which has its identifier (not a class name, storyboard identifier) set to `ViewControllerIndex`?;

Comment: @MilanNosáľ , yes i am, i set ViewControllerIndex to Storyboard ID

Comment: @AbarNew check if outlets are properly connected. When you delete them from the code but leave connections in storyboard and xibs, then they will crash at the time when view is loaded.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I added image

Comment: in that view, check `Use storyboard ID` under `Restoration ID` and tell me what happens

Comment: @MilanNosáľ not work for me, i added full code. please view again

Comment: use some debugging.. it seems like a forced unwrapped `nil` - identify where it happens and why..

Comment: it may be a crash inside the view controller's viewDidLoad that you want to present

Comment: @MilanNosáľ i added print(vcAboutUs) and got this error : <App.ViewControllerIndex: 0x7fe3ac42edd0>

Comment: where does it crash?

Comment: @Sh_Khan i checked it and not print anything : class ViewControllerIndex: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("GoMessage 1")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("GoMessage 2")
    }
}

Comment: @MilanNosáľ , This line : self.present(vcAboutUs, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: I think self is deallocated at this moment try to print anything in the class with self to verify that

Comment: @Sh_Khan, sorry i cant understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the name of VC to the storyboard?

[image]

Comment: Yes, please check my question. i added image from xcode